# SQL Server BLOB storage as files in file system

Tags: sql-server, storage, blob, varbinary

SQL Server BLOBs can use [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) which, as I understood, can make BLOBs be stored as separate files in a NTFS file system. But there is one thing I do not like: it is a setting for a whole SQL Server, whereas I want to change behaviour in single database or even for a single table. BLOBs should be accessible through stored procedures as before. Some solutions?

Comment: You need to **enable** the `FILESTREAM` options on a per-database level. And unless you actually **use** the `FILESTREAM` attribute on a column, nothing happens..... see [Introduction to SQL Server Filestream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) for a great intro and great info